# How to add link_to modal window in rails flash error messages from controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]I have a login_in page, When inactive users login I need to display a flash error message with a link stating "contact {email link} to activate again". On clicking of email link, I need to have a modal window, after which on submit of the modal window, I can send mail to support team. Can someone pleas help me how to proceed this?

```
def user_active?
    if (!params["user"].blank?)
      @user=User.find_by(:email => params["user"]["email"])
      flag = false;
      @LastSignInTimestamp = @user[:last_sign_in_at];
      @CurrentTimestamp = Time.now.utc;
      if(@LastSignInTimestamp != nil && @CurrentTimestamp != nil)
      @DateDifferenceInDays = (@CurrentTimestamp.to_date - @LastSignInTimestamp.to_date).to_i
      @profiles = Profile.where('name_key in (?) OR name_key LIKE ?', %w(Radial_ReadOnly), 'Portal-Account-Manager%')
      @profiles.each do |p|
        @user_profile_id = @user[:profile_id].to_s;
        @profile_id = p[:id].to_s;
        if(@profile_id.include?@user_profile_id)
          flag = true;
          break;
        else
          flag = false;
        end
      end
      end
      if (!@user.blank?)
        if(@LastSignInTimestamp != nil && @CurrentTimestamp != nil && @DateDifferenceInDays > @@DEFAULT_TIME_GAP && flag)
          flash[:error] = I18n.t('devise.failure.disabled').html_safe
          send_activate_email(@user[:id], @user[:last_sign_in_at])
        elsif (!@user.active)
          flash[:error] = I18n.t('devise.failure.inactive')
        elsif (!@user.email_verification_status)
          flash[:error] = I18n.t('signup.verification.not_yet_verified')
        else
          return true
        end
      else
        flash[:error] = I18n.t('login.errors.invalid')
      end
      redirect_to "/signin"
    end
  end
```

**en.yml** file

```
disabled: "Your account has been disabled due to inactivity. Please contact <a href>DL-PaymentsTeamHydra@radial.com</a> to activate again."
```

Comment: instead of sending email `<a href="mailto:temp@temp.com"> temp@temp.com</a>` when use click on this link, it will automatically take default email app from system

Comment: i am not able to view a link, it is coming as a text including tags. Can u please help

Comment: `disabled: "Your account has been disabled due to inactivity. Please contact <a href='mailto:PaymentsTeamHydra@radial.com'>DL-PaymentsTeamHydra@radial.com</a> to activate again."
`

Comment: Put this cutom link for now

Comment: Still i am not getting as a link, instead it is a normal text

Comment: Can you please share html which you received?

Comment: I have updated my post with the image, please have a look into this

Comment: Can you please add view of this flash error?

Comment: Try adding `.html_safe` to the link.

Comment: i added .html_safe still its not working